# Difference in Bluetooth of different devices?

Tags: bluetooth

How does iPad differentiate between a Bluetooth speaker and Bluetooth of a phone?

How do we restrict devices on bluetooth? Is there a signature in hardware or can we restrict or allow certain types by software?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. When a device connects it will advertise it's **Class of Device/Service** identifier this is a standard code that is used to tell the Bluetooth host what kind of device it's talking to and what the device is capable of 
https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/baseband
it also has a name field that it sends so the comptuer can say that device is a "iPhone" or a "Jaba Headset" instead of something like "000A3A58F310" (The devices BT id which seems to serve the same purpose as a mac address does on Ethernet)

How to tell your iPad, or any other device to reject the connection if the device attempting to connect is not using the proper Class of service is beyond me. But that is how it can tell the difference between the two. The name field is just for show, so we humans know what device is what on the list it's not used for anything else.